# how to confirm a event type?

Tags: events

I query all events, and decode the event a known type, but maybe some write them cause error, how to parse the event

```
pub fn decode_event(data: &str) -> Result<String> {
    let mut vec = Vec::from_hex(data)?;
    let events = Vec::<EventRecord<Event, H256>>::decode(&mut vec.as_slice())?;
    ...
    Event::frame_system(fs) => {
            m_event.module = "System".to_string();
            match *fs {
                frame_system::RawEvent::<node_runtime::AccountId>::ExtrinsicSuccess(d) => {
                    m_event.event = "ExtrinsicSuccess".to_string();
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("dddd:{:?}",fs);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

there is a build error:

```
 match *fs {
                      --- this expression has type `frame_system::RawEvent<sp_core::crypto::AccountId32>`
                frame_system::RawEvent::<node_runtime::AccountId>::ExtrinsicSuccess(d) => {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `frame_system::RawEvent`, found a different enum `frame_system::RawEvent`

= note: expected enum `frame_system::RawEvent<sp_core::crypto::AccountId32>` (enum `frame_system::RawEvent`)
found enum `frame_system::RawEvent<sp_core::crypto::AccountId32>` (enum `frame_system::RawEvent`)
= note: perhaps two different versions of crate `frame_system` are being used?
```

> Blockquote

Comment: `cargo tree -i frame_system` will tell you why you are pulling in a crate. Ideally you should only be pulling in one version of the crate.

Comment: my cargo.toml only one fram-system lib